# candlestick2_ochl() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ticksize'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a candlestick graph with matplotlib but it seems that *ticksize* shouldn't be assigned even though in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html) it is among the valid parameters.

I've imported the soon deprecated finance module and called it finance:

```
import matplotlib.finance as finance
```

And this is the incriminated line:

```
finance.candlestick2_ochl(candles, opens=prices_open, closes=prices_close, highs=prices_high, lows=prices_low, ticksize=1, colorup="#04E217", colordown="#DB0000")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is there in the documentation as you say, but it is not in the signature of the function. IDLE tells me the parameters are: `ax, opens, closes, highs, lows, width=4, colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=0.75`.

This module is deprecated so it is possible less care than usual has been taken over the documentation.

And `ticksize` is also not a parameter for the version of this function in the module `mpl_finance` that supersedes `matplotlib.finance`. So it looks like you're going to have to do without it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in the documentation. The [signature](https://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html#matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ochl) is

```
def candlestick2_ochl(ax, opens, closes, highs, lows,  width=4,
                      colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=0.75 )
```

from which it is apparent that no such parameter `ticksize` exists.